# Is there any way in spring boot to control shutdown mechanism?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Inside Spring-boot application, we have few processes that are running. When I receive terminate signal, I want to finish all the processes that are in processing and start no new process in that state and once all the process are processed then I would like to terminate the application. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achievement using [Actuator endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html) then you will have to [enable some endpoint](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-endpoints-enabling-endpoints) on your case is `shutdown`, in addition I can leave you a link that can help you, it has good information about it. 
- > [Shutdown a Spring Boot Application](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-shutdown) 
Kind regards.